# Ubuntu 19.04 freezes after starting it from grub

Tags: boot, grub2, freeze, 19.04

Two days ago I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my PC. The first time Ubuntu started without any problem, then the second time and onwards it freezes on a black screen after starting it from grub. I already tried booting Ubuntu with the `nomodeset` kernel boot option and nothing happened. It also freezes the entire operating system when I do something (the mouse cursor doesn't move or anything).

Comment: Look through these posts for similar circumstances: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze

Comment: Have the same problem, I even changed the motherboard as it appears to have something to do with the unavailability of display drivers from a relatively old PC. Same issue with the alternate machine as well.